# Outputting constantly changing text file data onto a webpage via Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, apache, raspberry-pi3

I have a python script that updates my output.txt file every 2 seconds. I'm able to output the txt file data to a webpage but for some reason it will not update until I restart the server. What I'm trying to do is have the webpage update the output.txt file data every 2 seconds. Here's what I'm using right now:

```
var reader = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');

function loadFile() {
    reader.open('get', 'output.txt', true); 
    reader.onreadystatechange = displayContents;
    reader.send(null);
    reader.onreadystatechange = outputData();
}

function displayContents() {
    if(reader.readyState==4) {
        var el = document.getElementById('main');
        el.innerHTML = reader.responseText;
    }
}

function outputData() {
    var refresh = 2000;
    update = setTimeout('loadFile()', refresh);
}
```

What I'm attempting to do is have the outputData function call the loadFile function every 2 seconds which is meant to re-read the output.txt file's updated data. Any help would be appreciated as I'm new to web programming. If it matters I'm running Apache on a Raspberry Pi 3 to create the webpage.

EDIT: Here is my python code in case it might be causing the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from datetime import datetime

var = datetime.now().time()

while True:
    print(var)
    with open("output.txt", "w") as txtfile:
        print(var, file=txtfile)
    var = datetime.now().time()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Is the request being made? Not certain what issue is?

Comment: @guest271314 I'm using <input type="button" value="button" onclick="loadFile()" ?>

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: @guest271314 When I click the button, loadFile() is supposed to run recursively and output the output.txt file contents to the web page every 2 seconds. For some reason it only outputs one instance of data and never updates.

Comment: And GET requests cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `outputData()` immediately instead of referencing the function to be called at `readystateschange` event. Remove

```
reader.onreadystatechange = outputData();
```

call `outputData()` within `displayContents` call. Call `loadFile()` at `window` `load` event.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var reader = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');

  function loadFile() {
    reader.open('get', 'output.txt', true);
    reader.onload = displayContents;
    reader.send(null);
  }

  function displayContents() {
    if (reader.readyState == 4) {
      var el = document.getElementById('main');
      el.innerHTML += reader.responseText + "<br>";
      outputData();
    }  
  }

  function outputData() {
    var refresh = 2000;
    update = setTimeout(loadFile, refresh);
  }

  loadFile()
}
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/EKh2DsmxtbzMYMlt1F4V?p=preview

Comment: I changed it but it doesn't seem to have changed anything.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. One thing I'm using though is <body onload="loadFile();"</body> instead of window.onload. Will that make a difference?

Comment: No worries. The result should be the same using `<body onload="loadFile();"></body>` http://plnkr.co/edit/Nl0vXR6nMKnAdYarxNeZ?p=preview

Comment: Have you tried first version of plnkr, which uses `window` `load` event? Have you checked the server request and error logs?

Comment: Okay, it seems to be working, but it is still not outputting the updated contents of output.txt.

Comment: What do you mean by "working" if the contents of "output.txt" are not being appended to `document`?

Comment: Sorry, not working but making more progress. I will try the window onload. I've added my python code in case it might somehow be the problem.

Comment: Are you missing closing quotes at `with open("output.txt, "w") as txtfile:`? What is purpose of `time.sleep(2)`? Have you browsed error logs at server?

Comment: I fixed the closing quotes. But the sleep(2) delays the python script. The python script will change the output.txt file's content every 2 seconds. I'm unaware of how to browse error logs.

Comment: What is logged at browser `Network` tab at `DevTools` or `Developer Tools` when the request is made?

Comment: Is a `Response` received every two seconds?

Comment: Yes, data will be outputted every two seconds similar to your plnkr setup, but the data never changes even when I change the contents of output.txt. Only after restarting the server will the data finally update on the webpage.

Comment: When you open `Network` tab at browser is a request made every two seconds? If not, issue appears to be a server issue?

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly, the reader.send(null); line throws ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Your server appears to be refusing connection.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense since it will work the first time, just not again after that.